# How to give two different colors in one scatter plot in Matplotlib based on values of y axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, jupyter-notebook, scatter-plot

So I want to plot a scatter plot with one dataset and have two different colors based on the condition that if a point is above a certain y-axis value, it is colored *red* (let's say) and below is colored differently.

[image: Currently, the plot looks like this:]

[image: And I want to make it look like this]

Comment: I am new to this platform so messed up a little on putting the images correctly and put them as a link. Just putting it out there for clarification.

Comment: As an FYI, SO is not a coding service. Please read the following documentation before posting another question. [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), & [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Always provide a [mre] with **code, data, errors, current & expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)** (plot images are okay) & you're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592).